# Cakephp ACL authentication issue - I'm locked out

Tags: php, authentication, cakephp, acl

I've followed the CakePHP Cookbook [ACL tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/view/641/Simple-Acl-controlled-Application)

And as of right now I'm just trying to add users using the scaffolding method. I'm trying to go to /users/add but it always redirects me to the login screen even though I have added `$this->Auth->allow('*');` in `beforeFilter()` temporarily to allow access to all pages. I've done this in both the `UsersController` and `GroupsController` as the tutorial asked.

Below is my code for `UsersController` which I think will be the most relevant of all the files. Let me know if any other piece of code is required.

```
<?php
class UsersController extends AppController {
 var $name = 'Users';
 var $scaffold;

 function beforeFilter() {
     parent::beforeFilter();
     $this->Auth->allow('*');
 }

 function login() {
    //Auth Magic
 }

 function logout() {
    //Leave empty for now.
 }
} 
?>
```

I think I've pretty much followed the tutorial, any ideas as to what I may be missing?

Thanks. I've been stuck on this for a while. =(

Comment: What do you have in your AppControllers beforeFilter()? As you will need to set the permission control to controller in order for Auth->allow() to work in the controller

Answer (score 1):

I followed the recent version of the tutuorial here:

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1543/Simple-Acl-controlled-Application

And then I found myself having issues with login and logout. However on adding the following lines, I was set ok!

in `users_controller.php`:

```
function beforeFilter() {
 $this->Auth->allow('login','logout');
}
```